# How to apply Asynchronoustask to imageview which comes in listview in android?

Tags: android, multithreading, listview

I have a listview in which i need to display image and textviews where
for the image also i'm getting url i'm using arrayadapter to implement
this in the listview.But while loading image i' facing problem.

```
BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions;
    bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = 2;
bm = LoadImage(image[position], bmOptions);
    resized = getResizedBitmap(bm, 150, 200);
    imdr1 = new BitmapDrawable(resized);
    holder.imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(imdr1);

private Bitmap LoadImage(String URL, BitmapFactory.Options options) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
    }
    return bitmap;
}

private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String strURL) throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    URL url = new URL(strURL);
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

    try {
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpConn.connect();

        if (httpConn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
    return inputStream;
}

public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newHeight, int newWidth) {

    int width = bm.getWidth();

    int height = bm.getHeight();

    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;

    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

    // create a matrix for the manipulation

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    // resize the bit map

    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

    // recreate the new Bitmap

    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height,
            matrix, false);

    System.out.println("in get resizebitmap" + resizedBitmap.toString());

    System.out.println("After resizing the image width is "
            + resizedBitmap.getWidth());
    System.out.println("After resizing the image height is "
            + resizedBitmap.getHeight());

    return resizedBitmap;

}
```

in the above shown way i'm reducing it.and loading it to my image view
but it's taking much time to show it in the listview here how can i'm
not aware of threading so anyone can help to solve this issue.Thanks
in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Run two threads separately one after another.First run thread for getting text and URLs(not loading images from URL) and then set the List view with Text only and display empty images.

after this run the second thread for loading images from URLs.After completion of this thread set list view again.

Note:For this you need to maintain separate Array-lists for text and images and in the adapter class check the items in the list view for Null.

Answer (score 0):

Run the above threads using Asynchronous Task. Asynchronous Task mainly contains three methods they are

onPreExecute - Handeling UI before thread.

onPostExecute -  Handeling UI after completion of thread.

doInBackground - Run your service here.

Comment: Here i need to put bm = LoadImage(image[position], bmOptions);
    resized = getResizedBitmap(bm, 150, 200);
    imdr1 = new BitmapDrawable(resized);
    holder.imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(imdr1); in the doinBackground.but how can i pass the required parameters and how can i getr back to it to the holderview.

Comment: call listviewid.setAdapter(parametrs if any) from onPostExecute method

Comment: i need image from url not total setadapter

Answer (score 0):

to know about the AsynkTask or threding read Article posted hear 
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Hear is the code snippet for the download the image using `AsyncTask`

```
public class AsyncFetchImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>{

    private WeakReference<ImageView> imageReference;
//  private WeakReference<Dialog> dialogReferance;

    public AsyncFetchImage(ImageView imageview) {
        imageReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageview);
//      dialogReferance = new WeakReference<Dialog>(dialog);
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... s) {

        return downloadImage(s[0]);
    }

    private Bitmap downloadImage(String url) {

        final AndroidHttpClient client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("Nixit");
        final HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);
        try {

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);
            final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if(statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK){
                Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error " + statusCode + " while retrieving bitmap from " + url); 
                return null;
            }
            final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if(entity != null){
                InputStream is = null;
                try{
                    is = entity.getContent();
                    final Bitmap bit = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                    return bit;
                }finally{
                    if(is != null)
                        is.close();
                    entity.consumeContent();
                }
            }


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } finally{
            if(client != null){
                client.close();
            }
        }
        Log.i("Image Fetch","Image Fetch Complete");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        if(isCancelled()){
            result = null;
        }
        if(imageReference != null){
            ImageView imageView = imageReference.get();
//          Dialog di = dialogReferance.get();
            if (imageView != null) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
//                di.show();
            }

        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

//downloading images from server..............
    public String[] DownloadAndSaveImageFromURL(String imageURL,String DirPath, String ImageName)
    {

```
String localurls[]=null;
 if(!sharedVariables.logoutFlagForStopingThreads)
  {
URL myFileUrl =null;
try {
myFileUrl= new URL(sharedVariables.evidenceImageUrl+imageURL);    
} catch (MalformedURLException e) { 
e.printStackTrace();
}
catch(NullPointerException e)
{ e.printStackTrace(); }
try {
HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection)myFileUrl.openConnection();
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.connect();
InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();     
   BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
   o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
   BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is,null,o);

   //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
   int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
   int scale=0;
       if(width_tmp>700 || height_tmp>700)
       {            
         scale=4;
       }      

   //Decode with inSampleSize
 BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
   o2.inSampleSize=scale;
   Bitmap photo=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(myFileUrl.openStream(), null, o2);   
if(photo!=null)
{   
    localurls=new String[2];

    localurls=Save_to_SD(photo, ImageName);  

}   

 if(photo!=null)
 {
     photo.recycle();
 }

System.gc();


}

catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    // TODO: handle exception
}

catch (IOException e) {



e.printStackTrace();
}
catch(NullPointerException e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}

  }else{

  }



return localurls;
}
```